# How to differentiate between login and logout in menubar in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am creating the session and i am able to login and logout efficiently. But my problem is in menu bar i have a option as login. **When the user clicks on it and logs in how to change the text Login to Text Logout?**

Like example

```
<a href"home.php">Home</a>
<a href"aboutus.php">Aboutus</a>
<a href"login.php">Login</a>
```

These are present in the main sheet as default. But when the user logs in i want it to be changed into

```
<a href"home.php">Home</a>
<a href"aboutus.php">Aboutus</a>
<a href"logout.php">Logout</a>
```

**automatically**. I know that we have to create a session and check for the user id ut exactly i dont know how. Please help me

Comment: How are you using the session to represent the logged-in state?

Comment: A strange question, seeing that you've already managed to implement a login system. You're probably already storing a user identifier in session (like in `$_SESSION['userId']`, depends on your implementation), so just do an `if (isset($_SESSION['userId']))`. For more info check http://ru.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use php to do that .. you create a php block which generates Login using echo..
it should be something like this

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) echo "<a href'login.php'>Login</a>"; else echo "<a href'logout.php'>Logout</a>"; ?>
```

Comment: giving error as Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to validate a login against your user database. If the login is valid, you will need to store that in a session.
You can store lots of information in a session, using PHP. The session id is sent back and forth using a cookie (this is an automatic process). Because of this, PHP will have this session information available on each consecutive request.

You can start a session an load session information by calling [session_start();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) at the start of each request.

You can read this session information in PHP using the `$_SESSION` superglobal and change the output accordingly.

A good, more detailed explanation on sessions and how to implement them using PHP is found in [this turorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php), although there are many others which may be just as good.

Answer (score 0):

try with that

when you try after put user email, password and click login button

//login.php

```
   public function check_login($emailid,$password)
   {

    $sql="select * from users where user_email='$emailid' and pwd='$password'" or die(mysql_error());
    $sql=mysql_query($sql);
    $user_data=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    $num_of_rows=mysql_num_rows($sql);

 if($num_of_rows==1)
 {

     $_SESSION['user_id']=$user_data['id'];
     return true;

 }
 else
 {
  return false;

 }
  }


session_start();

   if(!$_SESSION['user_id'])
    {
        echo '< a href"login.php">Login</a>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo"<span><b>Welcome <?php $_SESSION['user']; ?></b></span>";
        echo '< a href"logout.php">Logout</a>';
    }
```

Comment: giving error as Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Comment: after login fetch user id and store it $_SESSION['user_id'] and after then try

Answer (score 0):

You could put something like this in your "main sheet":

```
<?php if ($USER_IS_LOGGED_IN){ ?>
  <a href"logout.php">Logout</a>
<?php }else{ ?>
  <a href"login.php">Login</a>
<?php } ?>
```

You would have declare a `$USER_IS_LOGGED_IN` variable or find out if the user is logged in by some other means.

Answer (score 0):

A simple if statement. Something like the below:

```
<?php
$loggedin = logincheck($_SESSION['username'],$_SESSION['password']);
?>
<a href"home.php">Home</a>
<a href"aboutus.php">Aboutus</a>
<?php 
  if ($loggedin) {
?>
<a href"logout.php">Logout</a>
<?php } else { ?>
<a href"login.php">Login</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Note: I'm not sure how you're storing the login data, or how you're checking if the user is logged in or not. So this code will need changed to suit this.

Comment: i am checking by  <?php
 //Start session
 session_start();
 
 //Check whether the session variable SESS_MEMBER_ID is present or not
 
 if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) || (trim($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) == '')) {
  header("location: access-denied.php");
  
  exit();
 }
?>

Answer (score 0):

You should write an `isLoggedIn` function.
If the session's name is `uid` and its value is the `user id`, do something like this:

```
function isLoggedIn()
{
 if(!isset($_SESSION['uid']) || intval($_SESSION['uid']) == 0)
  return false;

 $uid = md5($_SESSION['uid']);
 $q = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM members WHERE md5(id) = '$uid'");
 if(mysql_num_rows($q) > 0)
  return true;
 return false;
}
```

And in your menu-bar write a condition:

```
if(isLoggedIn())
{
 echo "logout";
}
else
{
 echo "login";
}
```

Please notice that it's just an example , you need to re-write it for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

use session variables to identify if the current user is logged in, then make an if-else statement to get the desired functionality...

example---:

if the user is logged in create a session variable in your log in function:

```
function log_in()
{
   ...
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['user_id'] = 'user_id';
   ...
}
```

then try something like this on your desired place...

```
function check_log()
{
  if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
  {
    ...
    echo "<a href='logout.php'>logout</a>";
    ...
  }
  else
  {
    ...
    echo "<a href='login.php'>login</a>";
    ...
  }
}
```